# jQuery sliding banner mouseout doesn't work

Tags: jquery, slider, setinterval, clearinterval

While I move the mouse out of the sliding pictures,the setInterval function can't be restarted again.The pictures stops,and no sliding anymore.It seems there is something wrong with this code"  $("#wrapper-banner").mouseout(function(){timer()});"Anybody can help?Many thanks!

```
//slide banner
$("#wrapper-banner > div:gt(0)").hide();

 timer=setInterval(function() {
    $('#wrapper-banner > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#wrapper-banner');
}, 4000);
$("#wrapper-banner").mouseover(function(){clearInterval(timer);})

$("#wrapper-banner").mouseout(function(){timer()});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setInterval function returns a handle to the timer, not a function. It cannot be called like a function to restart it. I believe you what you want is to call setInterval a second time on the same function and replace the timer handle.

```js
//slide banner
$("#wrapper-banner > div:gt(0)").hide();

function moveNext() {
    $('#wrapper-banner > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#wrapper-banner');
}

timer=setInterval(moveNext, 4000);
$("#wrapper-banner").mouseover(function(){clearInterval(timer);})

$("#wrapper-banner").mouseout(function()
{timer=setInterval(moveNext, 4000);});
```